# Magento 2.3.3 dashboard is not loading

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento 2.3.3 with sample data. dashboard page is not loading. please suggest the solution[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run below command and check in which mode you are running your Magento.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

If you're running that in **Default** mode, then please run below command.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

After running above command please run this

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

And then go to your backend and just refresh the page.

Hope this solution works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your help. can you please tell me where i have to run these command? i am using braket. It will be great help if you can tell me the process in details.

Comment: You can connect your Magento in CLI (Command Line Interface) and then you need to run these all commands

Comment: Which operating system you're using ?

Comment: i am using windows 10

Comment: Okay then please do this **CTRL + R** and type cmd and enter

Comment: After that please go to your project directory using **C:/yourdirectory/magento**

Comment: You're running this project in local environment or you're getting this issue anywhere else BTW.

Comment: i am using local host (using Xampp).nothing happend after ctrl+r.

Comment: You can search cmd in your PC

Comment: I tried that. still not working anyways thanks for support

Comment: Did you run this command ? **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

Comment: i tried again and the problem has resolved. thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Can you please accept my answer @ashutosh ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all folders from the var and generated.
And run all this commands again.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 

php bin/magento indexer:reindex 

php bin/magento cache:flush 

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

And then again reload the page.

Thanks

Comment: Bro, i am non technical person, can you please tell me where i have run these commands. also, do i have to delete all the files and folders frm var and generated or just folder. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First Go to magento root directory then :

> vendor/magento/framework/view/element/tempalate/file/validator.php (dont exactly copy this url just follow this path)

open this file using any editor and change this line

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path); //you can comment this out
```

with this one

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\','/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

then goto to

> app/etc/di.xml

and search for `view_preprocessed`

you will find a whole line like this :

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

and change the **Symlink** with **Copy**

i hope this will help you make sure give a rep and make it working solution :)